# Does anisotropic filtering need a previously generated mipmap?

Tags: opengl, textures, mipmaps

I have a GPU which supports anisotropic filtering and a 1024x1024 soil texture. I would like to know, if I even need to create a mipmap when I am using anisotropic filtering or if I can just leave it out and only use anisotropic filtering.

I looked it up in some tuts and posts and each one had mipmapping enabled too, but they did not mention why.

I am not sure, but I think that I need a mipmap because I don't think that anisotropic filtering scales a texture from 1024x1024 to something like 512x512 or 256x256. Am I right?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? Enabling mip mapping is a simple 1 line kinda thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to enable mipmap for anisotropic filtering to work, but you should. Anisotropic filtering is an experimental feature on some GPUs, so the support rate is very low. To make sure the user gets close to the same experience as on other devices, you need both.

Comment: "Anisotropic filtering is an experimental feature on some GPUs, so the support rate is very low" - I'm not certain where you got that from; AF has been an absolutely standard feature across NV, AMD/ATI and Intel for over 10 years.

Comment: @LeComteduMerde You refer to it with GL_EXT, and you need to check if it exists before you use it. I have  pretty recent computer, which doesn't support it

Comment: GL_EXT is just because of IP issues; it's absolutely nothing to do with whether or not it's supported.  Please see https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/176138-GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic

Comment: @LeComteduMerde https://forums.oculus.com/vip/discussion/23329/no-anisotropic-texture-filtering-on-the-s6

Comment: The S6 has a mobile GPU.  Please don't confuse mobile GPU capabilities with desktop GPUs.

Comment: @LeComte 1) that was just the first example which came up on google 2) the OP never stated if he creates programs for PC or apps for cellphones

Comment: First sentence of the question: "I have a GPU which supports anisotropic filtering" - it's clearly not a problem.